# Compute $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} C_n (\frac{x}{4})^n$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

For $x\in (0,1)$, compute $$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} C_n \left(\frac{x}{4}\right)^n,$$where $C_n$ is the $n$th Catalan number, i.e. $C_n=\frac{\binom{2n}{n}}{n+1}$.
I came across this series while working on a different problem and I am pretty much stuck. I thought about using the integral representation of the Catalan numbers, which is $C_n=\frac{2 \cdot 4^n}{\pi}\int_0^1 t^n \sqrt{\frac{1-t}{t}}dt$, and this looks really nice, especially since the $4^n$ cancels out, but I don't know how to proceed. I am a bit of a newbie when it comes to series, so maybe this is really obvious.

Comment: Hint: use the generating function of $C_n$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The generating function for the Catalan numbers is, as can be found at [the OEIS](https://oeis.org/A000108),
$$\frac{1-\sqrt{1-4x}}{2x}$$
Now replace $x$ with $x/4$ to get the desired result:
$$\frac{2(1-\sqrt{1-x})}x$$

Answer (score 1):

Hints:

Use the fact that $S(x)^2$ can easily be calculated in function of $S(x)$ because of the induction formula linking Catalan numbers together $$C_{n+1}=\sum_{i=0}^{n}C_iC_{n-i}$$

Then solve the quadratic formula to find $S$.

If you are interested in the radius of convergence for this series, there is this paper

https://arxiv.org/pdf/1511.08555.pdf